# Is Bank for International Settlements still providing financial services to Afghanistan?

Tags: central-banking, international-economics, sanctions

After the Taliban takeover of Afghanistan in August 2021, most of the major central banks such as the Fed, Bank of England, and Bundesbank froze FX reserves of the Afghan central bank (DAB). As of June 2021, DAB had about $700 million with the Bank of International Settlements (BIS).

I have read many media and official reports covering this issue but I still haven't been able to figure out whether the DAB (under Taliban leadership) has been able to access its FX reserves with BIS. In all the media reports, BIS (being a super-secretive institution it is) has declined to comment on the issue. Does anyone have any insider information regarding the matter?

Comment: Politics SE may be a better home for this question.  The reserves were frozen for political reasons.